# Loop Through a CSV File In Python Not Working After Getting Number Of Rows

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script (Flask) using the csv module to load in a CSV file. I then need to count the number of rows in the file and then loop through each row, using a modulus to then pull the data out of every nth row. I'm experiencing a strange problem. If I hard code the row count the script runs as expected with the for loop executing and the modulus correctly flagging every nth row:

```
#rowCount = len(list(reader))
rowCount = 10000
```

But if I try and dynamically calculate the row count the for loop no longer runs. To be Clear the row count is calculated as expected but the following for loop is not executed and no error is returned. Does anybody have any idea why this is?

```
rowCount = len(list(reader))
#rowCount = 10000
```

Any advice would be gratefully received. Thanks.

```
def geoPartitioningReport(self, file):
    loopCount = 0
    file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../myFile.csv'), 'rU')
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

    #rowCount = len(list(reader2))
    rowCount = 10000

    noOfPartitions = 500
    partitionFrequency = int(rowCount/noOfPartitions)

    print ('-------------rowCount = ' + str(rowCount))
    print ('-------------partitionFrequency = ' + str(partitionFrequency))

    for rowdata in reader:
        print('aaaaaaaaaaa')
        if loopCount > 0 and loopCount != 1:
            if loopCount % partitionFrequency == 1:
                print ('---------------------------')
                print ('loopNo = ' + str(loopCount))
                print('column 0 = ' + str(rowdata[0]))
                print('column 1 = ' + str(rowdata[1]))
        loopCount += 1
```

Comment: Is it essential to know the row count? Simply reading every nth row would be straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

csv.reader returns generator. So you can't iterate it twice.
Use `row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)` to get num of rows instead.
Or num of rows is short, you can use `len(list(reader))` to receive number of rows.
The main thing here, `csv.reader` returns generator. More about generators you can find [here](http://intermediatepythonista.com/python-generators).

Comment: Thanks for the response Grynets. I’ve actually also tried using row_count = sum(1 for row in reader) and the result is the same. The loop fails to run. I’m reading the link you sent now..